# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/bitnami/postgresql/data’: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, permission-denied, camunda

I am installing Camunda 8 in a local Kubernetes cluster:

`helm repo add camunda https://helm.camunda.io`
`helm repo update`
`helm install camunda-platform camunda/camunda-platform`

And I wrote such a manifesto for postgres:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: data-camunda-platform-postgresql-0
provisioner: kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: camunda-platform
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
  name: data-camunda-platform-postgresql-0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: data-camunda-platform-postgresql-0
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 16G

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-camunda-platform-postgresql-0
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: camunda-platform
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
spec:
  storageClassName: data-camunda-platform-postgresql-0
  capacity:
    storage: 16Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data-camunda-postgres"
```

But outputting the Postgres pod log, I see this:

```
root@c1-control-plane:/opt# kubectl logs camunda-platform-postgresql-0

postgresql 14:08:23.32
postgresql 14:08:23.32 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 14:08:23.32 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
postgresql 14:08:23.33 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
postgresql 14:08:23.33
postgresql 14:08:23.34 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 14:08:23.36 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 14:08:23.36 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 14:08:23.37 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/bitnami/postgresql/data’: Permission denied
```

How to solve this issue ?

I read that it can help this:
`sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /bitnami/postgresql/data`
But I 'm not going to prescribe it with my hands every time , am I ? Besides, I have no way to get into the container

Comment: It's odd to see manual claims in combination with a helm chart. Does the helm chart not provide a way to give persistence? You want the `fsgroup` option in the container spec.

Comment: @jordanm That's what confuses me. I think maybe the reason is in my PV or PVC ?